# How this is working and not returning a warning validateDOMNesting(...)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, ant, components

I have this problem

```js
<Menu
  mode="horizontal"
  items={
    menuState &&
    menuState?.map((valueMenus, index) => {
      const key = index + 1;
      const items = valueMenus.menusInferiores;

      return {
        key,
        label: (
          <div>
            {valueMenus.menu} <DownOutlined />
          </div>
        ),
        children: items.map((item) => {
          return {
            label: <NavLink to={item.key}>{labelName}</NavLink>,
            key: item.key,
          };
        }),
      };
    })
  }
/>;
```

[result of console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4TGR.png)

but, I did  a little change like this :

```js
children: items.map((item) => {
  const labelName = item.label;
  //DONE:Cambiar la ruta quemada por la ruta que nos envian del bk
  item.label = <NavLink to={item.key}>{labelName}</NavLink>;
  return {
    label: <div>{labelName}</div>,
    key: item.key,
  };
});
```

[no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUs9J.png)
and it's working, my question is why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just wrraped your `<NavLink/>` component with a `<div>` this is what you did and this is working because `<a>` is no longer a descendant of `<a>` as mentioned is the error note that `<NavLink/>` is in fact an `<a>` element so instead of :

```
<a>
<a></a>
</a>
```

now you have :

```
<a>
<div><a></a></div>
</a>
```